# Which Dominion expansion playes best with two players?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue, dominion-prosperity, dominion-alchemy, dominion-seaside

I'm looking at picking up my first expansion for Dominion.  I play primarily with 2 players (total).

Which of the expansions would play best with two players, and why? (For example, a card like Tournament gets worse with more players, while a card like Pirate Ship gets better with more players. Which expansion, if any, seems to work best with two players.)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! We've recently decided to put an end to all "recommendation" questions(see the [FAQ](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq)). All the Dominion expansions are widely played by 2 and more players, I think any site with reviews will reflect this in their ratings. Please do bring us any more objective questions!

Comment: @user1873 Even if you took this to the extreme of "Which expansion cards play differently depending on the number of players?" that would just become a list question which wouldn't be a good question either.  I just don't think the question fits.

Comment: @bwarner, all answers are lists (of one). This wouldn't be a very long list, as ther are only a handful of expansions.